# Sidebar causing hot network questions to appear at bottom

Tags: bug

The side bar on meta is causing hot network questions to appear on the bottom of the page on my screen (Chrome Version 66.0.3359.170 (Official Build) (32-bit) on Windows 7). It looks pretty unintentional. When I submit this question the old right panel appears centered below the question.

Comment: Could you show of screenshot of what you mean? I don't think I have this issue

Comment: At work and screenshotting is blocked

Comment: Try a 40-inch monitor ...

Comment: I think [this has been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310916/388562) with a screenshot @James_Parsons :)

Comment: @AndréKool Thanks. I will close. Oh wait apparently I can't flag as dupe to Meta Stack Exchange